# Center crop image with background

Tags: android, layout, imageview

As the picture what i need to do, i try hard to do but I still not get the result.

**Result :**

[image: result]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"  // try this
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `scaleType` for this kind of result adding a background color should be enough.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:src="@drawable/hello"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```